# In Erlang how to get Client's ip and port?

Tags: tcp, erlang

In the following code , server is listening to port 2345. After accepting connection from client it returns `{ok, Socket}`

```
start() ->  
{ok, Listen} = gen_tcp:listen(2345, [binary, {packet, 4},  
                                  {reuseaddr, true},  
                                  {active, true}]),  
{ok, Socket} = gen_tcp:accept(Listen).
```

I want to get client's IP and port, how can I get them by analyzing socket?

Answer (score 6):

Use `inet:peername/1`. The description of the function from documentation:

```
peername(Socket) -> {ok, {Address, Port}} | {error, posix()}

              Types:

                 Socket = socket()
                 Address = ip_address()
                 Port = integer() >= 0

              Returns the address and port for the other end of a connection.
```

Comment: Thankyou! Is there a API like peername, that can get Server's ip and  port from Socket?

Comment: And what disturbs you from using peername with Server's socket?

Comment: I think he's asking how the server can get the local IP address and port number of the accepted socket. For that, you can use `inet:sockname/1`. See http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/inet.html#sockname-1 for details.

Comment: thank! what you say is what i asking,and i have figure out the problem.