# Retrieve client IP in :ranch

Tags: erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm using :ranch to receive TCP packges in my Phoenix application.

First I created a listener in the server using:

```
:ranch.start_listener(tcp_echo, ranch_tcp, [{port, 5555}], echo_protocol, [] )
```

How could I print the client IP in the `echo_protocol`?

Comment: I haven't used ranch, but don't you need to explicitly issue an accept with ranch? That's typically the pattern I'd expect to see. After an accept, information about the client should be available.

Comment: @DonBranson In ranch I sent the ack packge using `:ranch.accept_ack(ref)`. The `ref` is the alias to `tcp_echo` of the example, and I can't retreive the IP from there. Is maybe possible but I really don't know which function to call and the documentation doesn't show it clearly.

Comment: Wild guess: have you tried to examine process’ dictionary of the PID returned by `:ranch.start_listener`? You need a reference to the socket to [call `inet:peername/1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30389804/in-erlang-how-to-get-clients-ip-and-port#30390115) on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ranch includes a [sample echo application](https://github.com/ninenines/ranch/tree/master/examples/tcp_echo).

In `echo_protocol.erl`, there's an init function that accepts the connection from the client:

```
init(Ref, Socket, Transport, _Opts = []) ->
    ok = ranch:accept_ack(Ref),
    loop(Socket, Transport).
```

You can display the client ip address there:

```
init(Ref, Socket, Transport, _Opts = []) ->
    ok = ranch:accept_ack(Ref),
    {ok, {IpAddress, _}} = inet:peername(Socket),
    io:format("Client ~p~n", [IpAddress]),
    loop(Socket, Transport).
```

It will appear in a format like:

```
Client {127,0,0,1}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try it!